# Regex repetition group

Tags: c#, regex

Capturing a repetition group is always returning the last element but that is not quite helpfull. For example:

```
var regex = new RegEx("^(?<somea>a)+$");
var match = regex.Match("aaa");
match.Group["somea"]; // return "a"
```

I would  like to have a collection of match element instead of the last match item.
Is that possible?

Comment: `collection of match element`..can u elaborate it more

Comment: someting that implement ICollection?

Comment: `CaptureCollection` does that, as long as `Captures` is what you are after

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CaptureCollection

You can use `CaptureCollection` which represents the set of `captures` made by a single capturing group.

If a `quantifier` is not applied to a capturing group, the `CaptureCollection` includes a single `Capture` object that represents the same captured substring as the Group object.

If a `quantifier` is applied to a capturing group, the `CaptureCollection` includes one Capture object for each captured substring, and the `Group` object provides information only about the **last** captured substring.

So you can do this

```
var regex = new Regex("^(?<somea>a)+$");
var match = regex.Match("aaa");
List<string> aCaptures=match.Groups["somea"]
                            .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
                            .Select(x=>x.Value)
                            .ToList<string>();

//aCaptures would now contain a list of a
```

Comment: I know but I am not interested in the whole match. Semantics holds on the individual bits.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the `Captures` collection:

```
match.Groups["somea"].Captures
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the quantifier + to the thing you want to match, not the group, if you quantify the group that will create as many groups as matches are.

So `(a)+` in `aaa` Will create 1 group and will replace the match with the new occurrence of the match and `(a+)` will create 1 group with `aaa`

So you know what to do with your problem, just move the + inside the capturing group.

Comment: quantifiers used on groups **doesn't** create groups!

Comment: Actually I think it creates but as long as the group is the same, it will be replaced so you get the last match.

Comment: in your ans you said that it `would create 3 groups` not `overwrite`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this :

```
var regex = new RegEx("^(?<somea>a)+$");
var matches = regex.Matches("aaa");
foreach(Match _match in matches){
    match.Group["somea"]; // return "a"
}
```

This is just a sample but it should give a good start.
I did not check the validity of your regular expression though

Comment: That is one possible solution but you can not capture when the input is wrong. Ex. "aaba" will successfully match but it should not.

Comment: In my example you should reduce the RegEx to `RegEx("(?<somea>a)")` then it will only give groups of single character 'a'. Check it [here](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php)

Comment: `aaba` doesn't match `^(?<somea>a)+$`

Comment: it does not but my guess from @Nick.T suggestion was to use the regex `"a"` instead of `"^a+$"`.