# Capture multiple subgroups of repeated group

Tags: regex

Basically I want to capture multiple subgroups.
I am not [Repeating a Capturing Group nor Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)

If there is **aaa** I want to get the following subgroups:
*$1: a

$2: a

$3: a*

This could be achieved by **(a)(a)(a)**.

I am now trying to get this as something along the lines of **(a){3}** which unfortunately only results in
*$1: a*

EDIT:
I am trying to do this in Java. I already have another solution that uses StringBuilder to generate the correct pattern by repeating the capture group for the amount of expected occurences.
This question was more out of curiosity and because I was looking for a simpler way to do this.

What Some1.Kill.The.DJ mentioned is what I tried to do in Java.

Comment: Of course you are "repeating a capturing group". Which regex engine are you using? This is crucial for this question. Only .NET can capture an arbitrary amount of substrings. And it does it by repeating a capturing group. I am pretty sure there is no other case in which it is possible. However... what's your actual use case? Maybe you don't actually need to use capturing groups to achieve what you want.

Comment: Which engine / programming language? More examples of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I had answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580848/regex-repetition-group) and with the same example..also as buettner said only **.net** has it

Comment: @m.buettner: .NET is not the only regex implementation that can do that, but it _is_ a rare feature.

Comment: @MRAB I'd be glad to know about other ones (except for things like the one used in the JGSoft products like RegexBuddy which just mimicks other flavors)?

Comment: @m.buettner: There's a regex implementation for Python that supports it. It's on PyPI at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex.

Answer (score 0):

The actual use case and regex engine will be necessary to really answer this question, but for the example you provided this can be accomplished using a global pattern match with the expression `(a)`.  In python it would be done like this...

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "aaa"
>>> re.findall(r'(a)', test)
['a', 'a', 'a']
```

In Perl it would be the addition of the /g modifier, etc.  Global pattern matching will attempt to match the expression as many times as possible within the given string.